# How to split a string but miss a section under a special case

Tags: java

I basically want to split a string and skip the split if the split is encased in a char set. e.g

`(echo 1 <hello world> test apple <green trees>)`

I want the array to follow:

```
1 : echo
2 : 1
3 : hello world *OR* <hello world>
4 : test
5 : apple
6 : green trees *OR* <green trees>
```

Is it possible without losing order of the array? Thanks.

Comment: I've tried splitting the array via spaces, then looping over each element to see if it contains the encasing chars, if it does then it loops through the rest of the array starting from the index it found the encasing char and adds each element to the current element until it finds the ending character of the encasing. The problem is i'm left with a bunch of strings that are right but they have lost their order from the original string.

Comment: Post your code and we will help you fixing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(\w+|<.*?>)
```

---

```
MATCH 1
1.  [0-4]   `echo`
MATCH 2
1.  [5-6]   `1`
MATCH 3
1.  [7-20]  `<hello world>`
MATCH 4
1.  [21-25] `test`
MATCH 5
1.  [26-31] `apple`
MATCH 6
1.  [32-45] `<green trees>`
```

---

https://regex101.com/r/bS0mL2/1

---

```
/(\w+|<.*?>)/g
    1st Capturing group (\w+|<.*?>)
        1st Alternative: \w+
            \w+ match any word character [a-zA-Z0-9_]
                Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
        2nd Alternative: <.*?>
            < matches the characters < literally
            .*? matches any character (except newline)
                Quantifier: *? Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed [lazy]
            > matches the characters > literally
    g modifier: global. All matches (don't return on first match)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
String str = "echo 1 <hello world> test apple <green trees>";

List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("([^<]\\S*|<.+?>)\\s*").matcher(str);
while (m.find())
{

    words.add(m.group(1)); 
}

for(String word : words)
{
   System.out.println(word);
}
```

You can replace `words.add(m.group(1));` this section to remove the special characters

```
if(m.group(1).charAt(0) == '<')
{
    words.add(m.group(1).substring(1,m.group(1).length()-1));
}

else{
    words.add(m.group(1));
}
```